# matlab parpool failed when stopping mdce on one of workers node

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble using MATLAB cluster *MJS* (matlab job scheduled) during long running computation. When *MDCE* service is stopped on one of the worker nodes, **parpool fails** and I **lost all the data** obtained during calculating. 
The same situation occurs when using *PARFOR or SPMD*. 
1. Is it possible to save **parpool** in working condition when disconnecting a worker node?
2. How can I solve the problem of losing data when stopping MDCE process on one of the nodes of the cluster? Maybe I need to use a third-party Scheduler?

Comment: I am only aware of [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24279570/2732801) which unfortunately does not apply to a distributed computing server if I understand the documentation right. (Please double check this

Comment: Thank you! It helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: Using parfor-loop with parameter 'SpmdEnabled' set to "false" (for example: **parpool('mjs_cluster', 'SpmdEnabled', false)**) allows to keep evaluating a parfor-loop even if one or more workers aborts during loop execution. Checked.

Comment: Maybe I should read the documentation again, there is definitely something about the different cluster types I understood wrong.